# What SVN procedure should be used to merge Branch B onto Branch A?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

In SVN, consider:

- Branch A branches off the trunk
- Branch B branches off Branch A at a later time (is is considered to be a temporary development branch)
- Note that neither branch is the trunk.
- There are many directories and subdirectories (with files) involved in the branch
- Development was done on both Branch A and Branch B.
- During development on Branch B, Some new files were introduced, only on Branch B
- Branch A has had some files revised during this same time.  These changes were not applied to Branch B.
- It is desired to merge the changes of B (multiple revisions) and the new files that were introduced during B development onto Branch A (without losing the changes made to A while B was being developed).

What SVN procedure should be used to merge Branch B onto Branch A?

Edit:

So the whole procedure would be:

1. Create a working directory checking-out the latest branch `a files/directories`(Tortoise checkout)
2. perform (in this directory using Tortoise) Merge/"Reintegrate `a branch`, specifying branch b in the menu
3. Tortoise will do this merging onto the files/directories (is it into in my working directory ? (not yet in the SVN server?)
4. There may be reported merge conflicts...which need to be handled by a developer...
5. After what appears to be a successful merge , I perform an SVN commit and it goes into `branch a`

Are these steps accurate or does the merge operation automatically submit the changed files to the SVN server?  If so, in the event of merge conflicts, what happens?

Comment: Yes thats how it works. Have a look at the property svn:mergeinfo to check if svn is at the point where you expect it to be in the branch - merge - reintegrate cycle.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087650/svn-multiple-branch-tagging  @MalcolmFrexner do you think you could take a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would merge often from Branch A to Branch B.

> svn merge url://brancha url://branchb

When developemnt is done in Branch B you would reintegrate once (only once) Branch B into Branch A. After you reintegrated Branch B you have to stop working on Branch B.

> svn merge --reintegrate url://branchb

http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2008/07/subversion-merg/

Comment: And we assume the first step (svn merge url://brancha url://branchb) never happened. Tortoise offers 3 ways to merge. Which one to choose?

Comment: No matter if you never issued a merge against url://branchb. At the end you issue merge --reintegrate. In Tortoise its the second option of the merge menue ("Reintegrate a branch") used with the default settings.

Comment: I have edited question can you take a look and tell me if the whole procedure is what I believe it should be? (can't post it into comment as it's too big).

Answer (score 1):

As per your last comment, the steps which you have mentioned are perfectly correct.

And regarding your next question, svn will only help you in merging the changes and will NOT commit the changes for you on svn server.

You have commit the changes manually always after merging. :-)

Hope this helps.